# No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the applicationContext

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

Am trying to implement Section level security using **Spring3.1**. Using **Thymeleaf2.0** for my view part.  Here is the configuration i have made to do so,

### Jars Used## - All **spring3.1 jars** and **thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3.jar (version 1.0.0.beta-1)**

**SpringWebFlow-Servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
     ...
     <property name="additionalDialects">
     <set>
         <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
     </set>
     </property>
     ...
</bean>
<bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
     <intercept-url pattern="/productSelection" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    .....
 </http>
```

**xxx.html**

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This only be seen if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.
</div>
```

**Issue**

> Getting an Exception stating :
> No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the applicationContext

In Spring3.1, DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler doesn't implement WebSecurityExpressionHandler and the interface is deprecated. Please let me know the workaround as Thymeleaf is trying to search for the instance of WebSecurityExpressionHandler which is not available in ApplicationContext.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` does implement `WebSecurityExpressionHandler`. You can look at [the source](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java#L16) to check. Looking at the thymeleaf project, it only mentions Spring Security 3.0.x, so it may not be compatible with 3.1.

Comment: @Luke, I was using 3.1.0 and now i have replaced it with 3.1.2. This didn't resolve my issue but at least that exception has gone. Looks like it's a compatibility issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to define the bean in your application (root) context not in your servlet context.

```
<bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
```

I had same problem moved it from servlet-context.xml to root-context.xml and the bean is picked up.

Depending on your spring setup it can be in another xml file so check your web.xml for the Spring context root.

In your case if spring-security.xml is imported in your Spring root context you can add it there.

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` class in Spring Security 3.1.0 does not implement the `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` interface, which was probably an ommission.

This was solved in Spring Security 3.1.1 and newer versions, so you just have to update your Spring Security dependencies.

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for the reply. I have already done that and am no more getting that exception but somehow my  `sec:authorize` is still not working(See my Last Comment).

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old but for anybody who found there way here to complement Daniel's answer you can update your dependencies in your pom.xml by changing the following.

```
<properties>
    ...
    <!-- <spring-security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version> -->
    <spring-security.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>
```

I blogged about this as well with some more information if anybody is interested